# Ember 1.13.1 vendor/assets not loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Edit**

Problem appears to be having `brocfile.js` instead of migrating to `ember-cli-build.js`.  This article clears it up: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/TRANSITION.md.

I'm following along with the ember-cli 101 tutorial and we are supposed to get assets from picnic and fontello but the assets aren't getting recognized/loaded if I go to http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.css.  In fact, if I go there, the Ember console doesn't detect an Ember app at all.

I believe it might have to do with the content security policy changes I made just to make it not throw the violation to begin with:

config/environment.js:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'",
  'font-src': "'self'",
  'connect-src': "'self'",
  'img-src': "'self'",
  'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
  'frame-src': "'none'"
}
```

Brocfile.js:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({});

app.import('vendor/fontello/fontello.css');
app.import('vendor/fontello/font/fontello.ttf', {
  destDir: 'assets/fonts'
});
app.import('vendor/fontello/font/fontello.eot', {
  destDir: 'assets/fonts'
});
app.import('vendor/fontello/font/fontello.svg', {
  destDir: 'assets/fonts'
});
app.import('vendor/fontello/font/fontello.woff', {
  destDir: 'assets/fonts'
});

app.import('bower_components/picnic/releases/plugins.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/picnic/releases/picnic.min.css');

module.exports = app.toTree();


Bower.json includes: 

    "picnic": "~3.3.1"
```

My directory structure is:

```
Brocfile.js
bower_components
    --> picnic 
bower.json
vendor
   --> fontello
            --> font 
                  --> fontello.eot / .svg .ttf .woff
```

The source code for the tutorial is here: https://github.com/abuiles/borrowers.

Yes, I installed via Bower as well as restarted the server.

Comment: Its not Ember's fault, SPAs have a more difficult layer of abstractions. I think I'm facing the same issue, brb.

Comment: Maybe it's just Picnic.  I don't know.  I have to learn SPAs but haven't found them very easy to pick up.

Answer (score 2):

Its an `ember-cli 1.13.0` issue, in `0.2.7` it still works. Open issue: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4446

Comment: Ok, that would explain it.  Thank you.  I'll keep a watch on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem following the same tutorial.

Just to make a note i have found that if you use the broccoli command line with the command 'broccoli build dist', broccoli makes a new dist folder (once you have delete or make a backup of the previous) with a font folder with the fonts of fontello and writes the vendor.css with the data of picnic files as it is supposed to be.

But, if you run again ember server, it removes the fonts folder and leaves vendor.css in blank again.

At the moment is all i have found.

Comment: Thanks, it is an issue but the author is aware of it already: https://github.com/abuiles/ember-cli-101-errata/issues/224.  In the interim, I've also found that you just have to migrate to ember-cli-build instead of having broccoli like in https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4446.